# Leaflet setMaxBonds causing error

Tags: leaflet, bounds

My leaflet map with custom tiles is working properly until I try to set the max bounds for my map.

```
var SWCorner = new L.LatLng(-312, -180);
var NECorner = new L.LatLng(180, 312);
var MaxBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var map = L.map('map', { crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326, draggable: true }).setView([-63, 65], 1);
map.setMaxBounds(MaxBounds);

 L.tileLayer('http://localhost:9000/CustomIcons/tile_{z}_{x}-{y}.png', {
                boxZoom: false,
                minZoom: 1,
                maxZoom: 5,
                tms: true,
                noMoveStart: true,
                keyboardPanOffset: 10,
                noWrap: true,
                tileSize: 350
            }).addTo(map);
```

Things I have tried are:

### `var SOMmap = L.map('SOMmap', { crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326 maxBounds: new L.LatLngBounds([-312,-180],[180,312]}).setView([-63, 65], 1);`

`var SOMmap = L.map('SOMmap', { crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
                               draggable: true, maxBounds: MaxBounds }).setView([-63, 65], 1);`

---

```
var SOMmap = L.map('SOMmap', { crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
                               draggable: true
                              }).setView([-63, 65], 1).setMaxBounds(MaxBounds);
```

Whenever I try to set the max bounds, the tiles always vanish. How do I need to call the setMaxBounds?

Answer (score 0):

From http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/

```
EPSG:4326

WGS 84 

WGS84 Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000
Projected Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000
Scope: Horizontal component of 3D system. Used by the GPS satellite navigation system and for NATO military geodetic surveying.
Last Revised: Aug. 27, 2007
Area: World
```

So your values for the LatLngBounds are not valid in this projection lat should be between -180 and 180 , lng between -90 and 90